# how to create tables in R with my specific pattern?

Tags: r, datatables, kable, gt

I am trying to save time getting a table as in the example bellow but in R without myself coping and pasting from R into word [image]

My specific type of data I have that I want to transform into something similar with the above picture is right here:

```
test_data <-  structure(list(age_band = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("20-39", "40-59", "60+"), class = "factor"), 
        tested = c("positive", "positive", "showing symptoms", 
        "positive", "positive", "positive", "showing symptoms", "positive", 
        "positive", "showing symptoms"), comorbidities = structure(c(5L, 
        9L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("asthma", 
        "diabetes_type_one", "diabetes_type_two", "heart_disease", 
        "hypertension", "kidney_disease", "liver_disease", "lung_condition", 
        "obesity"), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 1L, 37L, 5L, 
        10L, 4L, 234L, 6L, 5L, 12L), percentage = c(50, 50, 45.7, 
        38.5, 35.7, 30.8, 30, 21.4, 17.9, 14.8)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), groups = structure(list(age_band = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("20-39", "40-59", 
    "60+"), class = "factor"), tested = c("positive", "positive", 
    "positive", "positive", "positive", "showing symptoms", "positive", 
    "positive", "showing symptoms", "showing symptoms"), comorbidities = structure(c(1L, 
    5L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("asthma", "diabetes_type_one", 
    "diabetes_type_two", "heart_disease", "hypertension", "kidney_disease", 
    "liver_disease", "lung_condition", "obesity"), class = "factor"), 
        .rows = structure(list(8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 
            3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
        "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

With my specific data  - I want Age Band `20-39; 40-59 and 60+` just like `2015; 2016; 2017` in the table above and right under each age group I want `tested and showing symptoms` categories just like `write` and `pass rate` for each comorbidities in alphabetical order -  `asthma, cough, chills etc` (which should appear on the side as rows - just like `'Ontario RN university program collaborative partner, and language instruction'`. I want counts and percentages to be kept.

Is this possible in R? I have Kable but it does not do that way I want. There must be something similar?

====== Updated question ====

If this is possible with gt library please let me know? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`tables` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf):

```
library(tables)
tables::tabular((comorbidities = factor(comorbidities)+1)*((n=1)+Percent("col"))~(age_band=factor(age_band))*(tested=factor(tested)), data=test_data)

                          tested                    tested                    tested                   
 comorbidities             positive showing symptoms positive showing symptoms positive showing symptoms
 asthma            n         1.00     0                1        0                0        0             
                   Percent  33.33   NaN               50        0                0        0             
 diabetes_type_two n         0.00     0                0        0                0        1             
                   Percent   0.00   NaN                0        0                0       50             
 hypertension      n         1.00     0                1        1                1        1             
                   Percent  33.33   NaN               50      100               50       50             
 obesity           n         1.00     0                0        0                1        0             
                   Percent  33.33   NaN                0        0               50        0             
 All               n         3.00     0                2        1                2        2             
                   Percent 100.00   NaN              100      100              100      100
```

You can then export the result in the format you prefer, for example, `toHTML`:
[image]

Comment: is this possible with RMarkdown ?

Comment: Yes, either as Latex or HMTL, see page 43 of [linked vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf).

Comment: I get an error: 'Error in Percentage("col") : could not find function "Percentage" '

Comment: surprising, I tested again with `reprex` and it works on my computer. Did you load `tables`? Also, my code uses `Percent`, so I don't fully understand the error on `Percentage`.

Comment: because in my real table it is Percentage. Hmm, I also loaded the table library

Comment: `Percent` is a reserved key word applied on each column to get the percentage

Comment: I takes a while to get accustomed to the `tables` syntax, but it's powerful

Comment: I actually changed to percentage but it does not do the job. It may be because it is not a data frame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222268/discussion-between-waldi-and-gab).

Comment: did you get my chat messages?

Comment: no I didn't : no notifications from my browser : looking at it right now

Comment: that is odd. I have sent several messages. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: perhaps my add blocker stopped the notification popups...

Comment: thank you. it worked is just that I raised other things as the table I have may need a bit of changes. I added a picture in the chat to show you